# Error installing drools 7.38 plugin in Eclipse 4.15

Tags: eclipse, jboss, installation, drools

I am trying to install the drools plugin in Eclipse on Windows.  The version of Eclipse that I installed is 4.15.0 build 20200313-1211.

I then went to https://download.jboss.org/drools/release/7.38.0.Final/ and downloaded droolsjbpm-tools-distribution-7.38.0.Final.zip and set that up as a local update site.

When I select "Drools and jBPM" and click "Next", I get an error message about these two items:

- JBoss Runtime Drools Detector
- JBoss Runtime Drools Detector Developer Resources

with this error messsage:

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could
>   not be found.   Software being installed: JBoss Runtime Drools
>   Detector 7.38.0.Final
>   (org.jboss.tools.runtime.drools.detector.feature.feature.group
>   7.38.0.Final)   Missing requirement: JBoss Runtime Drools Detector 7.38.0.Final (org.jboss.tools.runtime.drools.detector.feature.feature.group
>   7.38.0.Final) requires 'org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.jboss.tools.runtime.core.feature.feature.group 0.0.0' but it could
>   not be found

I don't know anything about Eclipse or Drools so I might be trying to install the wrong thing.  I've been looking at all of the tutorials I can find about getting Drools up and running.  Every tutorial I've found leads me to a dead-end like this.  Am I installing the correct software to test Drools?

Comment: Ty just putting the update site addess in to "Install new software" - `https://download.jboss.org/drools/release/7.38.0.Final/org.drools.updatesite/` that should let the install find any other components it needs

Comment: Thanks Greg.  Being totally new to Eclipse/Drools I don't know what 'putting the update site address to..." means.  Are you saying I need to add that URL as another repository in the "Install New Software" dialog?  I tried, but got the same error.